# Having 6 gb of RAM with intel i3 processor is worthy or not?

Tags: memory

I had a laptop with 2gb of RAM and Intel i3 processor. Later on I started coding. 2gb of RAM is not enough for me now so I was planning to add another RAM of 4 gb. But shop's technician recommended me to add only  2gb and make it 4. Adding 4 and making it 6 is worthless with i3. Is that true ?

I need recommendation.

Comment: -1 due to lack of even simple research.  (and no, it is very much **not** true). Use a different shop which has people who know what they sell.

Answer (score 1):

Most current (and previous generation) i3s should be fine with up to 16 GiB of memory. What the technician may have had in mind (but didn't say) is that with 2 * 2 you will have your memory running in dual channel mode whereas with 2 + 4 you will most probably be limited to single channel. The principle of "the more, the merrier" would far outweigh the gains you would have from dual vs. single channel though.

Comment: exactly..he used words similar to that you said...

so in overall which on is better 2+2 or 2+4??
thanks in advance

Comment: Theoretically if you have an application that depends much more on bandwidth than on memory size, 2+2 will be better. In practice that's very rare and 2 + 4 will be better. The ideal case would be for you to sell the 2 GiB if you can and get a 2 * 4 kit.

Comment: Even if he does get a mismatched pair the fact that he has an i-series processor means it supports hybrid dual channel whereby it will use dual channel up to the 4gb with the remaining 2gb falling back to single channel, its still a boost. If he only had a single 2gb to begin with it would still be faster as at least now there would be *some* dual channel ram. http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/cs-011965.htm#flex @AawazGyawali

Comment: I'd still put a pair of 4s in it. 6GB ain't much to work with these days. Always assuming it's a 64-bit OS of course, which hasn't been mentioned so far.